# Calling multiple gradle tasks in a task

Tags: gradle

Currently I'm trying to create a gradle task that will run all unit test for different projects in one call. Here is what I have:

```
tasks.create(name: 'taskA', type: Test, dependsOn: ':projectA:unitTest')
tasks.create(name: 'taskB', type: Test, dependsOn: ':projectB:unitTest')
tasks.create(name: 'taskC', type: Test, dependsOn: ':projectC:unitTest')

task runAllUnitTests(type: Test) {
  dependsOn tasks.findByName('taskA')
  dependsOn tasks.findByName('taskB')
  dependsOn tasks.findByName('taskC')

  tasks.findByName('taskB').mustRunAfter('taskA')
  tasks.findByName('taskC').mustRunAfter('taskB')
}
```

When I just have it run taskA and taskB, it runs fine.  However when I add taskC to it, it doesn't run it.  Is there something I'm missing?

One thing to note is that taskB has some failed tests.  Could this be what's stopping the execution?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my theory was right.  If a test fails, it doesn't progress forward.  All it took was adding a `--continue` to the gradle command to make it run all the way through.

Comment: You can also add startParameter.continueOnFailure = true into settings.gradle

Comment: Also gradle.startParameter.setContinueOnFailure(true) in the task itself also works.